# how do I check the size of a directory and add "didnt change after time x"

Tags: linux, bash, monitoring, check-mk

I am monitoring witch Check-MK and i know how to get this skript as a service right into Check-MK.

I need just the skript:
check the directory size and I want to get an alert if it didnt change after 1,5h

to check the folder size:
folder_size=$(du -bs /backup/log |

after the "|" i want to check this with time
am I right so far?
thx for help <3

Comment: Do you want to detect changes in the folder size or a modification in the folder?

Comment: @Fravadona 
i have the directory /backup/log
i just want to check like every 10sek if the size changed.
if didnt change after 360 rounds (1hour) : "echo xyz"
else : check again

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple [local check](https://docs.checkmk.com/latest/en/localchecks.html), that does what you need, if Checkmk's built-in file age checks do not meet your requirement.

Comment: i know about the local check and that u can add a service with that.
But i dont know how to write the skript to check the date of the last ritten file und compare it again after 1h or 1,5 days.